# Check if element is in clientHeight

Tags: jquery, element, viewport

I want to set a div at the bottom of the page.

If the main content div is smaller then the client height, then it should appear at the bottom of the page.

If the content div is bigger, then the div should be set below the content div.

Here are two images to explain my problem better:

[image: http://www.suckmypic.net/25999/7903846b.png]

[image: http://www.suckmypic.net/26000/45dfbe5c.png]

Can anybody tell me the logic how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to do this, your looking for a `sticky footer` type that in google and you'll get lots of results.

give this a try: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily.

```
var winHt = $(window).height();
var contentHt = $("#content").height();
var footerHt = $("#footer").height();

if (winHt >= contentHt) {
    $("#footer").css("top",winHt-contentHt-footerHt);
}
```

See these two demo pages:-
Case 1: When content div is smaller then window -> http://jsbin.com/otulog/2

Case 2: When content div is larger then window -> http://jsbin.com/otulog/3